# Xcode 8 it takes forever to land on breakpoints

Tags: xcode8

I just upgraded my Xcode to `Version 8.0 (8A218a)`, when I insert some breakpoints and run a project, it just stops for like two minutes then goes to one breakpoint and then takes another two to go to the next one.

Update: `Step over` also behaves the same (very SLOW).

Does anyone else using 8.0 meet this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.But it only happen in iOS8.It won't happen in simulator or iOS9+.So,upgrading your iOS version may solve this problem.

Comment: I'm developing apps and I have to work with all of the versions that are above 7...

Answer (score 0):

In my case Xcode 8 automatically added a lot of variables to Debug area including those not available in the current context. Hiding debug area significantly improved performance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.happen in iOS10.Delete Breakpoints and disable source control.Has been resolved.

Comment: How to disable source control?